# Stroke outline of captured object

Tags: object, colors, processing, outline, stroke

For a project, I have to follow a little chopper that's painted green. I want to follow the helicopter with a webcam and have the outline stroked on my screen. How would you do this?

I am using Processing for this.

Comment: What do you have so far? Which specific part are you stuck on? It's pretty hard to answer general "how do I do this?" type questions.

Comment: I think the words to google are: tracking, blob detection, tracking algorithm. And Processing of course. You can even say `blob detection site:processing.org`. As general as it gets :)